# Conditional triggered in Airflow DAG's taking more time to trigger next DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have 10 airflow DAG's, we are running the next DAG by using conditional trigger. But that next DAG is not starting immediately. It is taking exactly 5 minutes to trigger.

Example:

Dag1 completed at 10:05
Dag2 is started at 10:10

If we can able to eliminate the 5 minutes Gap, the total ETL process will completed with in 2.5 hrs. But now it is taking around 3 to 4 hours.

Config File:

```
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600 
parallelism = 8 
dag_concurrency = 64 
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True 
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16 
load_examples = False 
donot_pickle = False 
dagbag_import_timeout = 30 
workers = 4 
worker_class = sync 
authenticate = False 
filter_by_owner = False 
email_backend = airflow.utils.send_email_smtp 
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor 
celeryd_concurrency = 16 
job_heartbeat_sec = 5 
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5 
task_cpu = 1
```

Comment: Can you post your trigger/configuration setup?

Comment: sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600
parallelism = 8
dag_concurrency = 64
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
load_examples = False
donot_pickle = False
dagbag_import_timeout = 30
workers = 4
worker_class = sync
authenticate = False
filter_by_owner = False
email_backend = airflow.utils.send_email_smtp
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor
celeryd_concurrency = 16
job_heartbeat_sec = 5
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
task_cpu = 1   this is the parameters we set in the config file,..!!!